# Synchronize directories of different networks over FTP

Tags: file-synchronization, ftp

I'm looking for a software that allows me to sync two directories of different networks by using an FTP share in between. Ideally the FTP share would not hold the complete data of the source directory, but function as kind of a temporary directory to transfer missing files from source to destination.

Are there any recommended software products that do such thing well?

Many thanks, Best Regards Alex

Comment: What is *"FTP share"*? Where do you want the software to run?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I think it might be a directory accessible over ftp from many networks. (Compare to "smb share")

Comment: Sorry if that was imprecise. I'm talking about a regular ftp server that provides an ftp directory thats reachable from both networks. I don't have a preference as to where the software should run.

Comment: So the software would have two run on both machine then, right? Side A would upload the list of its files to the FTP server. The the Side B would take the list and upload its changed files and the list of its files. The Side A would download the uploaded files and upload its changes files, etc. I've never heard of software like this. But it can be scripted, if needed.